# Javascript refresh / reinitialize DOM

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dom, page-refresh

On my website I have something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('classname').on("click", function(e){
    // do stuff...
  });
});
```

Then the dom is manipulated without reloading the page. Maybe some new elements with class="classname" are added. For these elements the click event is not triggered. Is there any way to reinit the dom for javascript without reloading the page? In jquery, something like `$.reinit()`?

Just in case it matters, the dom manipulation is done with rails `<%= j render partial: '...' %>` included in a update.js.erb file.

Basically I'm looking for a way to tell the dom there is a new/updated element.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the eventListener to the document and then check if the clicked element has the needed class. In plain JS it would look like:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if(event.target.classList.contains("classname")) {
    // do stuff...
  }
});
```

This way you won't have problems with new elements that are added to the DOM.